# random SIGABRT in DTXChannel serializer queue while running tests on iOS 12 Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

Starting with Xcode 10 and iOS 12 our CI Server randomly fails because one ore more tests crash on the Simulator.

The log file states something like

```
Test Case '-[SJDNotificationToObjectIDMarshallerTest testItMarshalsAnObjectID]' started.
Test Case '-[SJDNotificationToObjectIDMarshallerTest testItMarshalsAnObjectID]' passed (0.003 seconds).
objc[43030]: Attempt to use unknown class 0x7fe4a241cfa0.

Restarting after unexpected exit or crash in SJDNotificationToObjectIDMarshallerTest/testItMarshalsAnObjectID; summary will include totals from previous launches.
```

The test cases vary in different runs. The error `Attempt to use unknown class` is always the same.

It is very hard to reproduce, since it occurs only every second test run on our CI Server (Mac Mini). On my quite faster MacBook Pro it happens very rarely. But I did reproduces it on my machine a couple of times. While running the tests Xcode would pause and show the crashed thread. The backtrace says:

```
* thread #2, queue = 'DTXChannel serializer queue [x1.c1]', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x000000010ba5801e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload + 10
    frame #1: 0x000000010ba53561 libsystem_kernel.dylib`abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 82
    frame #2: 0x000000010ba5350f libsystem_kernel.dylib`abort_with_reason + 22
    frame #3: 0x0000000108ae91f5 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, __va_list_tag*) + 108
    frame #4: 0x0000000108ae911e libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_fatal(char const*, ...) + 127
    frame #5: 0x0000000108af1409 libobjc.A.dylib`lookUpImpOrForward + 645
    frame #6: 0x0000000108afe814 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
    frame #7: 0x000000010951ac23 CoreFoundation`__21+[__NSSetI __new::::]_block_invoke + 51
    frame #8: 0x000000010951ab1a CoreFoundation`+[__NSSetI __new::::] + 474
    frame #9: 0x0000000109570ed4 CoreFoundation`+[NSSet setWithObjects:count:] + 52
    frame #10: 0x0000000109571eab CoreFoundation`-[NSSet setByAddingObjectsFromSet:] + 763
    frame #11: 0x000000011c015f44 DTXConnectionServices`-[DTXProxyChannel _allowedClassesForReturnValues] + 109
    frame #12: 0x000000011c016722 DTXConnectionServices`__42-[DTXProxyChannel _sendInvocationMessage:]_block_invoke + 260
    frame #13: 0x000000011c024e76 DTXConnectionServices`__51-[DTXChannel _scheduleMessage:tracker:withHandler:]_block_invoke.751 + 101
    frame #14: 0x000000010b6a651d libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    frame #15: 0x000000010b6a7587 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #16: 0x000000010b6ae058 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 720
    frame #17: 0x000000010b6aeb9b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 401
    frame #18: 0x000000010b6b79c6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 645
    frame #19: 0x000000010ba9061c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 409
    frame #20: 0x000000010ba90415 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going on?

It is reproducible in Xcode 10 GM as well as the current Beta 10.1 10O35n in every Simulator running iOS 12 or 12.1 Beta.
It is not reproducible on iOS 11 Simulator.

Comment: Hey. Did you figure out what was that?

Comment: no idea. this is really annoying since round about every second ci build crashes. I filed a radar, lets see if Apple replies. Have you seen similar crashes?

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a lot of time trying to solve the same problem.

The best workaround which solved this problem for me was removing `OCMocks` for `NS-classes`: `NSString`, `NSArray` etc.

I have no information on the side-effect of this, but this solution worked for me.

Comment: very interesting. I am going to check that out. We are indeed mocking System Framework classes. In a particularly flakey test we even mock UIApplication.